# Azure AD authentication for only a part of the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to use Azure AD authentication for only a part of the application?

I work for a school and our team is creating a web application where some users need to sign in with their work/school account.
Other users can create an individual account and sign in with that. They will use a different part of the application.

The first thing the user should see is a page where he can choose what kind of user he is.
If the user is an "external user", he can sign in with his individual account.
If the user is a "teacher" or "student", he can sign in with his work/school account via Azure AD.

Something like this.

[image]

Is this what "Home page URL" is for on the Azure portal under Branding?
The app still immediately shows the Azure AD sign in page when I fill this in.

Or do we need to use Azure AD B2C? Or does that only work for social identities like Google, Facebook, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD and OpenID auth flow to achieve this.

More details in this question [Mixing Azure AD authentication with Forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999304/mixing-azure-ad-authentication-with-forms-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this what "Home page URL" is for on the Azure portal under Branding?

You can register multiple authentication schemes  in you application , one is authentication using local database , and one is authentication using Azure AD . You should make the login page in your application not on Azure side , and has  buttons to trigger diffident scheme , for example ,AAD scheme :

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
     return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" } , AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 }
```

The simplest way is to use ASP.NET Core Identity and add Azure AD authentication as external login . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60200747/5751404) is code sample .

For authorization part , you can manage users and roles inside local database since by default , after AAD login , identity framework will help create a local user in database , but that is also can be customized depends on your requirements . Or you can directly create policy and check the claims of users , users login from AAD or  local database should have different claims .